# Recording Sky Player TV using Windows Media Center

Tags: streaming, windows-media-center, recording, tv

Is there a way of recording TV such as live sport on Sky Player using Windows Media Center? It has a built in extension for Sky Player doesn't seem to have recording functionality.

Has anyone else tried this with any luck?

Comment: I don't think you currently can record anything other than on-demand movies etc. You could try asking this at http://home4film.com to get more thoughts from HTPC users though.

Answer (score 2):

You can record Sky Player when downloading as a stream to your PC using [WM Recorder](http://www.wmrecorder.com/), but not afterwards.